# Unix Command Operations

Tags: linux, unix

Lets say there is a file in linux which has lines which are space separated.

e.g.

```
This is linux file
This is linux text
This is linux file 1
This is linux file 3
```

Now I want to only print those rows which has 5th column present in the lines of file. In this example my output should be 3rd and 4th line ( with 1 and 3 as 5th column )

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Why was this question marked as a duplicate for one requesting help with `awk` when this question does not mention, or request, help with `awk`?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `awk` and its `NF` (number of fields) variable, as per the following transcript:

```
pax$ cat inputFile 
This is linux file
This is linux text
This is linux file 1
This is linux file 3

pax$ awk 'NF >= 5 {print}' inputFile 
This is linux file 1
This is linux file 3
```

This works because the basic form of an `awk` command is `pattern { action }`.

The pattern selects those lines (and sometimes things that *aren't* lines, such as with `BEGIN` and `END` patterns) which meet certain criteria and the action dictate what to do.

In this case, it selects lines that have five or more fields and simply prints them.

Comment: Since the default action is `print` this can be simplified to `awk 'NF >= 5'`

Comment: Thanks so much Pax!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `awk`, you can also do it very simply in bash (or any of the shells) by reading each line into at least five fields, and then checking to insure the fifth field is populated. Something like this will work (it will read from the filename given as the first argument (or `stdin` if no name is given))

```
#!/bin/bash

fn="${1:-/dev/stdin}"

while read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5; do
    [ -n "$f5" ] && printf "%s %s %s %s %s\n" "$f1" "$f2" "$f3" "$f4" "$f5"
done <"$fn"
```

**Example**

Using your data, the snippet above produces the following output:

```
$ bash prn5flds.sh dat/5fields.txt
This is linux file 1
This is linux file 3
```

(note: depending your your shell, `read` may or may not support the `-r` option. If it doesn't, simply omit it)

Comment: Thanks David, this works!

Comment: Glad to help. Strange your question was marked as a duplicate for a question requesting help with `awk`, when your question does not mention, or request, help with `awk`. Go figure...